# Gnu Make >$* and $* meaning

Tags: c, makefile, x86, gnu-make, osdev

i stumbled upon a Makefile that look weird i couldn't understand it

here is the that Makefile

```
AS=as -32 -Iinclude
LD=ld -m elf_i386
CC=gcc -m32 -fno-pie -fno-stack-protector
CPP=gcc -E -nostdinc -Iinclude
CFLAGS=-W -nostdlib -Wno-long-long -I include -fomit-frame-pointer

.s.o:
    ${AS} -a $< -o $*.o >$*.map

all: boot setup

boot: boot.o
    ${LD} --oformat binary -N -e start -Ttext 0x0000 -o boot $<

setup: setup.o
    ${LD} --oformat binary -N -e start -Ttext 0x0000 -o setup $<

clean:
    rm -f boot setup *.o *.map
```

the part that i didn't understand is this

```
.s.o:
    ${AS} -a $< -o $*.o >$*.map
```

what is the significance of `.s.o` in this case 
and what this `$*.o >$*.map` trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.s.o:` is a suffix rule that exists for compatibility with old versions of make. It is the same as the pattern rule `%.o : %.s` . `$*` is an automatic make variable  containing the base of the source file name (in this case the filename without the extension `.o`).

The command generated for processing `boot.s` to `boot.o` would be:

```
as -32 -Iinclude -a boot.s -o boot.o >boot.map
```

GNU Assembler(AS) option `-a` generates a listing file to standard output. Standard output is being redirected by the *nix shell (via `>`) to a file name ending in `.map`. The end result in this example is that `boot.s` will be assembled to an object file called `boot.o` and standard output will be written to the file `boot.map`

**Note:** I personally would have redirected standard output to a file name with the extension `.lst` rather than the `.map` extension.